# Opening file from Java

Tags: java, api, desktop

What I need is to instruct OS to open the file with the default program used for that file type. Exactly as if, i.e., that file was double-clicked by user under Windows.

The purpose is, i.e., "your PDF file was generated. Click here to open it".

In platform-independent way, if possible...

I dont know exact terms for what I want, so if someone could update tags, I'd most appreciate that ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the [Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class, and the [open()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) method in particular.

> Launches the associated application to
>   open the file. If the specified file
>   is a directory, the file manager of
>   the current platform is launched to
>   open it.

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 6, we have [`Desktop.open()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)) for exactly that purpose.

Comment: what about 1.5 or before.. any reference ?

Comment: @Nrj: there was no platform-independant way to do it before Java 6. You could use Runtime.exec() to call platform-specific mechanisms via the shell, such as Windows' *start* command.